# Why Python Fitter auto-rescales plot y-axis?

Tags: python

How does Python Fitter rescale the y-axis? For example, in these images from [Rahul Raoniar medium blog](https://medium.com/the-researchers-guide/finding-the-best-distribution-that-fits-your-data-using-pythons-fitter-library-319a5a0972e9): you can see that the y-axis is rescaled automatically by applying distribution fitters. How are they rescaled?
[image: plot image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a perfect answer but from what I can see in the article you shared, here are my suspicions:

1. The user performed a 0 to 1 and forgot to disclose it in the article.
2. One of the distributions that he tried to fit requires that the data be normalized between 0 and 1 and it performs this normalization automatically.

I am leaning toward the 1st option because after reviewing the source code, it doesn't seem like the "Fitter" function is doing any auto normalization.

Check the source code out here: https://fitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/fitter/fitter.html#Fitter